# Correct regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I need a php regex that matches    `http://bla/bla/bla/variable-text/numbers/`

where blass are always the same, variable text changes and can have inside some minus (-) and after the slash as numbers there are 5 digits.

I've tried some regex, but i'm quite rusty and i cannot find the right one, the one i've tried is

```
/(http:\/\/bla\/bla\/bla\/)([:alnum:]-)\/([:num:]{5})/
```

but it doesn't work.

Any suggestion?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex in PHP:

```
~\b(http://bla/bla/bla)/([\da-z-]+)/(\d{5})\b~i
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wY1fX3)

Comment: Thank you anubhava for the answer, altough yours is right, i've accepted the other one because is simpler.

Comment: Simpler doesn't mean correct. You wrote `after the slash as numbers there are 5 digits` and other answer will allow anything (even empty string) in that segment.

Comment: Let me know if this doesn't work for you in someway or you need more help with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
/http:\/\/bla\/bla\/bla\/.*?\/(.*?)\//
```

[Working Link](http://regex101.com/r/pT6tJ4)

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
%^http:\/\/bla\/bla\/bla\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/\d+\/$%
```